# Intellij IDE not downloading dependencies after pom update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, ide

I'm using Intellij IDE for Spring projects. Whenever I add a dependency in pom file, it's not downloading it. In the case of Eclipse IDE, it automatically downloads the dependency whenever a dependency is added in pom.xml file.

[image]

I added the highlighted dependencies in the pom.file but it's not downloading. How to configure the IDE for auto-download dependencies whenever the pom.xml is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse project build automatically it that option is enabled as build automatically

but idea we can not load maven dependency just by adding it in pom.xml but we can build the project by

IntelliJ Idea - Preferences

Select “Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler” -- build Project automatically

Above will build the project but it will not download the dependency
We have to click reload all maven project icon under maven tool window which can be activated by view - Tools Windows - maven

Answer (score 1):

You can tick the checkbox "Import Maven Projects automatically"

under **"settings" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment "
-> "Build Tools" -> "Maven" -> "Import Maven projects automatically"**

Usually, if do some modification in **pom.xml**, the Intellij will give always suggest you to enable Auto Import in a small pop-up(). I think it might have suggested you already. Anyways, you can do the above.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for Maven and found it was not present under Build, Execution, Deployment.

Even though this plugin was shown under Plugins, it was in "Disabled" state and after explicitly enabling; it solved the problems.

I'm not sure the great ( ? ) reason to keep this in disabled state and changing UI every release of IntelliJ.

Compared to XCode, VSCode, Eclipse and other IDE; IntelliJ quality is really bad.

[image]

Comment: I did this, even though Maven isn't downloading the dependencies. Instead after installing a plugin and ensuring its enabled, I ran the command  Maven-> clean install , its showing compiler errors as Spring boot library isn't present.